# Mobile devices - Override viewport scale settings to implement a zoom/pan media viewer?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, scaling, viewport

I have a responsive layout with a fixed header. When scaling (zooming) is enabled via the viewport meta tag, the layout can break when the user zooms because the header also zooms - which is BAD. (I wish I could keep just the header in place without scaling no matter what the current scale setting is). Anyway, that's why I'm use the following meta tag that disables scaling:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

My goal is to implement some sort of media viewer like Facebook that overrides the viewport settings of the document. Upon closing, it should restore everything back to normal. I tried opening an iframe that loads a document that can scale, but it seems like the parent document overrides the iframe.

FYI, I'm using jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Just discovered that with jQuery you can do this:

```
var meta = $('meta[name=viewport]');
$(meta).attr('content', 'device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=5');
```

I could get more fancy... like getting the original setting first and then restoring it when you're done. I tested this on iOS 6 and it works. I have not tested it on other devices.

Comment: Brilliant! I have a small web view in an iPad app, needed to override device-width, and this works perfect: `[theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"var meta = $('meta[name=viewport]'); $(meta).attr('content', 'width=320, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=5')"];`